# Magento 2 - Customers not receiving notifications for bad login/reset password

Tags: magento2, frontend, login, customer-account

I believe the theme I'm using completely missed out implementing these things.

How can I do this properly myself?

Answer (score 0):

make sure cron job is running in your website and if you have installed a new theme than please run below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work...  Hmmm